# Laravel real time location track?

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, geolocation, real-time

I want to track drivers car on map and I am wondering if that possible in **Laravel**? 
Do any one has any tips or some documentations for Laravel real-time location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Laravel Pusher to get real time activity tracking.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Laravel is for back-end purpose, for example, to render different views to the user, access records from DB(Active Records) etc. You cannot build a real-time application with Laravel only. You need to use for example socket.io, pusher. However, Laravel provides wrappers for these technologies, you've might have heard of Laravel Echo. If you want to understand how to build your desired real-time application a good place to start is to first read about broadcasting in Laravel -https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting, also this https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-laravel-with-socket-io-e7c7565cc19d is quite helpful for you to understand how to combine Laravel with socket.io

Good luck!